# Why is "http://my.archive.ubuntu.com" very slow?

Tags: updates, 12.10, download-speed

I am currently updating my freshly installed Ubuntu 12.10 and it's taking a very long time. Most of the time i get a download speed of 222B/s. The highest has been 1kB/s. Can anyone fix this problem? Its really not worth waiting for more than an hour for a 5MB update. (My internet download speed goes up to around 224KB/s).

(Dated 24th October, 2012)

Comment: I have had similar issues, but its only during certain times of the day, I concluded its likely because everybody is getting 12.10, and everybody is doing updates.

Answer (score 0):

1. Was the server my.archive.ubuntu.com working before? It might be a one-time problem that will go away. Try again tomorrow.
2. Consult with your local community team: http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/ubuntu-my or http://www.ubuntu.com.my/ -- try sending them an e-mail or in irc (click on the "letter" or "chat bubble" icons under "resources") or even create a new forum topic.
3. Join #canonical-sysadmin on IRC Freenode: irc://chat.freenode.net/canonical-sysadmin -- say something like: *hi, the mirror server my.archive.ubuntu.com is very slow, can you change it to point to some other mirror?*

Try other servers Malaysian servers and see which one is adequately fast: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors#yui_3_5_1_1_1351080392505_75

Answer (score 0):

Also consider:

- On the output from the repo, there's the line `manage by: chenhaw@osacyber.org`. Consider sending them an email about the bandwidth status.
- This is hosted at Multimedia University (mmu.edu.my). They may have just started term and therefore may have organic or artificial bandwidth restrictions in place for quality of service needs.
- There's just been a release. Lots of people doing upgrades means repositories tend to go a lot slower. Just how things work. Pair this with it being hosted on a network that gets used for other things, and that mignt mean the University has traffic limits up.

Comment: I think you might be right. Anyways, I switched my software source to the main server (http://archive.ubuntu.my) and the updates got downloaded just fine. Thanks for helping.